# (Javascript) How do I calculate the sum of <td> elements of a particular class, when the class is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic

I have a function that adds a new row to a table every time a button is pressed. The class of each  element in the table is dependent on the selection of a drop-down menu, and is determined like so:

```
var a = document.getElementById("dropDown");
let dependentClass = a.options[a.selectedIndex].id;
```

A new row is added on the click of a button using the following code:

```
let newRow =<tr><td class='thc "+dependentClass+"'>"+thc+"</td><td class='pm25 "+dependentClass+"'>"+pm25+"</td><td  class='pm10 "+dependentClass+"'>"+pm10+"</td></tr>";

$("#operations").append(newRow);
```

So I add this new row, creating  elements with dynamic class. This process is repeated may times, creating many different  elements.
How do I use javascript/JQuery to calculate the sum of all  elements with one particular class?
Here is what I am trying:

```
let k = 0;  
parsed.data.forEach(arrayWithinData => {
    let dependentClass = parsed.data[k][0];
    if($("#operations td").hasClass("thc "+dependentClass)) {
        console.log("we have a "+dependentClass);
        console.log($("#operations td.thc."+dependentClass).text());
    }
    k++;
})
```

the dependentClass is derived from a parsed .csv file, by using the index parsed.data[k][0]
This code finds every  element with the selected class on the page, and logs the text. The problem is, the process is repeated for every  that has the selected class, and I only want it to iterate once to get the sum. Please let me know if any additional information is needed... My mind is pretty boggled over this.

Comment: Please provide the minimal working code so we can see how your data is structured. :)

Comment: @JoelHager I'll work up an edit to the post, one se

Answer (score 0):

You should select dynamically created elements by using some static parent element.
For example)

```
var count_of_td = $('body #tableID td.className').length;
```